# how can aws service update the corresponding redis cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis, amazon-elasticache

Currently I have several redis clusters for different env. In my code, I will write data to redis inside my lambda function, if I deploy this lambda to my aws account, how can it update the corresponding redis cluster? Since every environment has its own redis cluster.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a config file with Redis cluster name and their hostnames and in code, you can pick different clusters based on the env provided.

If you are using roles in the AWS account, for each environment then you should also do STS on requirred role

Comment: I have these config file, show as above, and they have different redis nodes, my question is, when I deploy this service to aws, how can it update the corresponding redis cluster? Can you please provide more detail on "you can pick different clusters based on the env provided.", thanks

Comment: You neeed to deploy three lambdas with env name for each.  Something like python3 deploy_some_lambda.py --prod python3 deploy_some_lambda.py --qa

Answer (score 0):

Your resource files are just files. They will be loaded by your application following different strategies, depend on your application's framework and how it has been configured.

Some application, at build-time, apply the correct configuration, by passing a flag to the build for example. `--uat` or `--prod`. If your application is one of those kind, you can just build the correct version and push it to AWS. They will connect to the correct Redis, given that you put the redis configuration into the ENV files

The other option is to use Environment Variable
[image]